# How to embed external websites with IE8

Tags: 2007, content-editor-web-part, page-viewer-web-part

Using IE7 and Firefox I can use Page viewer web parts & Content editor web parts to embed external web sites i.e. 
[Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/embed/JbeFIfS8uno)
[Kart Club Celebrates 50th Anniversary](https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/39145028?secret_token=s-YU32B)

However with IE8 only the youtube clip is visable.  The web parts embedding soundcloud show as white with no content.  How do i make the soundcloud clip visable in IE8?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that SoundCloud is loading also a Flash using

```
<embed name="sm2movie" id="sm2movie" src="/player/assets/swf-a0e10171/soundmanager2_flash9.swf" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="always" bgcolor="#ffffff" pluginspage="www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" title="JS/Flash audio component (SoundManager 2)" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" haspriority="true">
```

You should try to embed direclty the Flash using a CEWP or via a JS file loaded by the CEWP, as such (all the extra are simply DIVs)

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"
WIDTH="550" HEIGHT="400" id="myMovieName">
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="myFlashMovie.swf">
<PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
<PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#FFFFFF>
<EMBED src="/support/flash/ts/documents/myFlashMovie.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF WIDTH="550" HEIGHT="400"
NAME="myMovieName" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash"
PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```